# ALAssetsLibrary ask user for permission when saving to an album? Why?

Tags: ios

I have a game where users can take a screen shot and it will save it to a custom album named after the game.  When I try and do this, iOS asks the user if the App can have access to their location information, if they say no, then the screen shot is not saved in the custom album, but rather the default album.

Why is it asking permission to use location information?  I'm just taking a screen shot.  It has nothing to do with the camera.  I'm just copying the opengl surface and making a UIImage out of it.

This is how I'm saving the UIImage:

`- (void)writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(CGImageRef)imageRef orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)orientation completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock;`

Is location information being put into the screen shot?  If so, can I disable that so this warning doesn't come up?  My game has no need for location information and I'd hate for users to think I'm tracking them.

This seems like a crazy warning since it's completely factually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the following link,
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> This method will fail with error
>   ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError if the user has not enabled
>   Location Services (in Settings > General).

However, we have found that there is not location permission request in iOS 6. Maybe iOS 6 has other privacy control on Photos. So you don't need to asking location permission. Our solution is check the *[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]* and only save to custom album while iOS >= 6.